# WinUI 3.0 Desktop: Background color of TextBox gets changed on mouse over

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, winui-3

I have started to work with WinUI 3, the new UI tech from Microsoft.

I have a `TextBox` that I want to set to readonly, i.e. `IsReadOnly="True"` (Remark: The user shall still be able to copy content from it, that is why I do not want to set it to disabled, i.e. `IsEnabled="False"`.)

When setting it to `IsReadOnly="True"` I noticed that the `TextBox` still keeps its default white background. I wanted to change this, in order to avoid having users clicking on it because they think that it is possible to change its content.

I decided to set some kind of grayish color for the background:

```
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Background="SlateGray" Text="The content..."></TextBox>
```

This works as expected, but with one problem: **As soon as the mouse hovers over the `TextBox` the background changes back to white**. When the mouse is no longer over the `TextBox`, the color changes back to the specified gray background color.

In WPF I would have tried some DataTrigger in order to keep the formatting, but there are no DataTriggers (yet?) in WinUI.

I also tried setting other color related properties on the `TextBox` in order to see if they have anything todo with the mentioned behavior, but setting these did not change anything:

```
FocusVisualPrimaryBrush, FocusVisualSecondaryBrush, SelectionHighlightColor, SelectionHighlightColorWhenNotFocused
```

I am open for all kinds of suggestions on how to keep the background color when the mouse is over the readonly `TextBox`, thank you.

Comment: [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.isreadonly?view=winui-3.0) says it should be "grayed" for most themes. Have you any event that may reset the color ? or inherited css styles like `textbox:hover` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could override some theme resources:

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Background="SlateGray" Text="The content...">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundPointerOver" Color="SlateGray" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundFocused" Color="SlateGray" />
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please point out how your approach was to find the names / keys of the resources you mention in you answer? Where can I see that these resources affect the background color of the TextBox? I guess in the code of the theme, but where do I find it and how do I find 'Text box related resources' in the theme code?

Comment: @Martin - found key names here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.19041.0\Generic\generic.xaml" (your exact location may vary)